# What if my user name contains at sign '@' when use golang sql to connect mysql?

Tags: mysql, go, database-connection

Application needs a user whose name contains `@` character, I found it seems that golang-sql will crash while name contains `@` and password is empty, just like

```
sql.Open("mysql", "root@proxy@tcp(172.21.30.22:3306)..")
```

Comment: Try [`Config.FomatDSN`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#Config.FormatDSN) to make the driver code do the necessary stuff itself.

Comment: @kostix I don't think [this helps in this case](https://go.dev/play/p/lFYzhT5Ra32) - as the `@` is not escaped. I've definitely seen the MySQL driver trip up with specially characters in the password - even when using `Config.FormatDSN`. So the OP's credentials may not be possible with the current mysql `Go` driver.

Comment: If so—I mean even if the stock function tasked with preparing a syntactically correct DSN cannot cut it,—it's a bug worth reporting upstream.

Comment: [This manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting-using-uri-or-key-value-pairs.html) from MySQL says to use `%40` instead of `@` where applicable and also suggests an alternatve approach it calls "key-value pairs". I'd try both of these things. Still, I'd also report a bug.

Answer (score 1):

When you use special characters in your usernames you should use quotes to separate the username from the domain name

For example

```
sql.Open("mysql", "'root@proxy'@'tcp(172.21.30.22:3306)'")
```

Comment: not worked.....